# Ionic app requesting user permission for camera on Android emulator, but not in Ionic DevApp

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

## Problem

I am currently learning Ionic 4 by following this tutorial 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app

However instead of using Cordova like they do in the tutorial I plan on using Capacitor. I followed the Capacitor setup guide and used the camera example given in their official documentation.

I made sure the following permissions are in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then I ran this in my terminal:

```
ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external
```

This opens up Android Studio and prepares my project.

## Working on Android Emulator

I then press the run selected configuration button which installs the application on my emulator. When I press the camera button I get asked to give the app permission to:

- Allow app to take pictures and record video?
- Allow app to access photos, media and files on device

Then it loads up a camera in the emulator like this and I can take a picture as I am supposed to for this tutorial (Embedded image below because it's huge).

## Issue with same app using Ionic DevApp

However when I try to use the camera within the Ionic DevApp by manually entering the server URL in capacitor.config.json, I don't get asked for the above permissions. Pressing the exact same button does nothing in the application.

I tried manually giving Ionic DevApp application permission on my physical device but that does not seem to resolve the issue as the button still does nothing.

#### Emulator

- Emulator API: 28
- Emulator Android Target: Android 9.0

#### Physical device

- Physical device: Samsung S8+
- Android version: Android 9.0

### Images

[image: Emulator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic devApp is for Cordova only

Comment: Ah I see, I'll just use a cabel for Capacitor then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- Add the permissions to ionic app : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions

2- Remove --external since it doesn't work, right commend :
ionic cap run android --livereload --consolelogs --serverlogs

I don't know why it doesn't work on --external mode !